# ¿Cómo enviar un archivo de un formulario de angular a python?

Tags: html, python, django, angularjs

Como puedo enviar un archivo que lo "cargan" desde una formulario en html, tengo que enviarlo de angular a python.

¿Cómo hacer que me envíe el archivo de angular a python?

Este es el código:

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div ng_show="ticketActivo.carga" style="margin-left: 70px;">
         <input type="file" name="archivos" value="Mouse" ><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

angular --> ticketactivo es el objeto donde guardo todos los valores del formulario.

```
   $scope.actualizaStatusTicket = function () {
        console.log($scope.ticketActivo.comentarios);
        if($scope.ticketActivo.comentarios !== null && $scope.ticketActivo.incidencia !== null){
            console.log("entro");

            fd.append($scope.ticketActivo);

            var ruta = '/atn/tickets_web/api/ticket/actualiza/?var1=34';
            $http.post(ruta, fd,{
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined
                })
                .success(function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $scope.consulta = false;
                $scope.respuesta = false;
                $scope.finalizado = true;
                $scope.mensaje = data;
                inicializa();
            });

        }
    };
```

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que utilices la etiqueta `AngularJS`, la versión de `AngularJS` es diferente al framework `Angular`.

Comment: ya esta amigo,muchas gracias, tu podrias ayudarme con mi problema?

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas un poco sobre django rest framework para que así puedas conectar tu app de angular con django

Comment: @JonathanGarcia Aun tienes problema?

Comment: si aun sigo tentendo el mismo problema, no se si sea demasiado claro en la pregunta y lo que coloco, espero me puedas ayudar @TheVicious